# Export nested BigQuery data to cloud storage

Tags: java, json, google-cloud-datastore, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to export bigquery data to google cloud storage bucket via the API. I adapted a code snippet from here
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data

```
Job job = table.extract(format, gcsUrl);
// Wait for the job to complete
try {
  Job completedJob = job.waitFor(WaitForOption.checkEvery(1, 
TimeUnit.SECONDS),
      WaitForOption.timeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES));
  if (completedJob != null && completedJob.getStatus().getError() == null) {
    // Job completed successfully
  } else {
    // Handle error case
       System.out.println(completedJob.getStatus().getError());
  }
} catch (InterruptedException | TimeoutException e) {
  // Handle interrupted wait

}
```

I have exchanged format with "JSON" since my data is nested and can't be exported to CSV and the gcsUrl with "gs://mybucket/export_*.json".
 But the error messages tells me the following problem:

```
transfer not working  BigQueryError{reason=invalid, location=null, message=Operation cannot be performed on a nested schema. Field: totals}
```

Any advice what to do? JSON should be able to handle a nested format...

Comment: In your code, how is `format` defined?

Comment: for format I use JSON

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Referring to the [destinationFormat option](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.extract.destinationFormat), you should set `"NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON"` for the `format` variable in order to export as JSON.

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been marked as solved but I got the same error while doing it in Python and the `extract_table()` method in Python doesn't take in the `destination_format` argument, so for anybody using Python trying to achieve this here is how to export it in JSON format:

```
# Basically one has to pass job_config instead of destination_format
# Configuring Job Config to export data as JSON
job_config = bigquery.job.ExtractJobConfig()
job_config.destination_format = bigquery.DestinationFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON

extract_job = client.extract_table(
    table_id,
        destination_uri,
        job_config=job_config,
        # Location must match that of the source table.
        location="US"
)

extract_job.result()
```