# My first BigQuery python script

Tags: database, python-3.x, python-requests, google-bigquery

I would like to know how to create a python script to access a BigQuery database.
I Found a lot of script but not really a complete script.

So, I Would like to have a standard script to connect a project and make a query on a specific table and create a csv file from it.

Thanks for your help.
Jérôme.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pprint
import argparse
import sys
from apiclient.discovery import build

def export_data_to_gcs(dataset_id, table_id, destination):
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client(project='XXXXXXXX-web-data')
    dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_id)
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)

    job = bigquery_client.extract_table(table_ref, destination)

    job.result()  # Waits for job to complete

    print('Exported {}:{} to {}'.format(
        dataset_id, table_id, destination))

export_data_to_gcs('2XXXX842', 'ga_sessions_201XXXXX', 'gs://analytics-to-    deci/file-name.json')
```

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried so far?

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pprint
import argparse
import sys
from apiclient.discovery import build
def export_data_to_gcs(dataset_id, table_id, destination):
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
    dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_id)
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)
    job = bigquery_client.extract_table(table_ref, destination)
    job.result()  # Waits for job to complete
    print('Exported {}:{} to {}'.format(
        dataset_id, table_id, destination))
export_data_to_gcs('2XYZERT42', 'ga_sesXYZ_20180121', 'gs://x')

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but your question should be as self-standing as possible.  Please put the code (the relevant parts of it) in to the question itself

Comment: Have you read through the [docs](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/usage.html)? They are quite good and have lots of examples.

Comment: I found how to add project_id. Now I have a error 400: Bad request operation cannot be performed on a nested schema. Fields : Totals

Comment: I have just tried your code as is, only changing parameters, and it works fine for me. Maybe you can try using `NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON` for the `format` as explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44908879/export-nested-bigquery-data-to-cloud-storage)

Comment: Do I have to create a job config like `job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()` ?

Comment: Found it : I have to add this in my SQL query
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST

Answer (score 0):

#### Destination format

BigQuery supports CSV, JSON and Avro format.

Nested or repeated data cannot be exported to CSV, but it can be exported to JSON or Avro format.

As per the google documentation - 
[Google Document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#bigquery-export-table-gcs-python)

Try other formats as said.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud.bigquery.job import DestinationFormat, ExtractJobConfig, Compression

def export_table_to_gcs(dataset_id, table_id, destination):
     """
     Exports data from BigQuery to an object in Google Cloud Storage.
     For more information, see the README.rst.
     Example invocation:
     $ python export_data_to_gcs.py example_dataset example_table \\
       gs://example-bucket/example-data.csv
    The dataset and table should already exist.
    """
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
    dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_id)
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)
    job_config = ExtractJobConfig()
    job_config.destination_format = DestinationFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
    job_config.compression = Compression.GZIP
    job = bigquery_client.extract_table(table_ref, destination, job_config=job_config)
    job.result(timeout=300)  # Waits for job to complete
    print('Exported {}:{} to {}'.format(dataset_id, table_id, destination))
```