# Not being able to export a Big Query table

Tags: php, google-bigquery

I am trying to export a Big Query table into cloud storage using NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON as destination format but I keep on receiving the following error:
**Error running job: Operation cannot be performed on a nested schema**.

I know Big Query allows to export nested tables if you choose the json format (as it is stated both on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.extract.destinationFormat) and on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44908879/export-nested-bigquery-data-to-cloud-storage)), so I don't understand how come I am getting this error...
I am using the PHP SDK and this is the code I've been using:

```
extract_table($projectId, $datasetId, $tableId, $bucketName, $objectName);


function extract_table($projectId, $datasetId, $tableId, $bucketName, $objectName, $format = 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON'){
    $bigQuery = new BigQueryClient(['projectId' => $projectId,]);
    $dataset = $bigQuery->dataset($datasetId);
    $table = $dataset->table($tableId);
    // load the storage object
    $storage = new StorageClient([
      'projectId' => $projectId,
    ]);
    $destinationObject = $storage->bucket($bucketName)->object($objectName);
    // create the extract job
    $options = ['destinationFormat' => $format];
    $extractConfig = $table->extract($destinationObject, $options);

    $job = $table->runJob($extractConfig);
    // poll the job until it is complete
    $backoff = new ExponentialBackoff(10);
    try {
       $backoff->execute(function () use ($job) {
           print('Waiting for job to complete' . PHP_EOL);
           $job->reload();
           if (!$job->isComplete()) {
               throw new Exception('Job has not yet completed', 500);
           }
        });
    } catch (Exception $e) {
    }
    // check if the job has errors
    if (isset($job->info()['status']['errorResult'])) {
        $error = $job->info()['status']['errorResult']['message'];
        printf('Error running job: %s' . PHP_EOL, $error);
    } else {
        print('Data extracted successfully' . PHP_EOL);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are using the wrong `options` field configuration. Following the [PHP documentation on the `Table.extract` method](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.66.1/bigquery/table?method=extract), you will see that the `options` field in the `extract` method must be a `configuration` object such as the one presented in the [BigQuery documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration).

You are defining your `options` object as:

```
$options = ['destinationFormat' => $format];
```

Instead, you should use the format:

```
$options = ['configuration' => ['extract' => ['destinationFormat' => $format]]];
```

This is because the `destinationFormat` field is nested under `configuration` and `extract`.

Comment: Hello Dsesto, thanks for your reply. I am going to change the code straight away and I'll let you know if it works. Thanks again.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot! It's weird though as I used the code that you can find on php docs samples official github page (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/api/src/functions/extract_table.php).

Comment: That does not look right to me. I'll make sure to report this internally and correct the GitHub example if this is indeed an error. Thanks for pointing it out!